# Альтернатива вложенным массивам

Tags: массивы, objective-c

Мне нужно создать сложную структуру данных, скажем, массив 4 уровня вложенности, в котором некоторые уровни с символьными ключами (как NSDictionary), некоторые - с цифровыми (как NSArray). Если использовать для этого собственно NSArray и NSDictionary, то возникают проблемы с памятью (память не освобождается там где-то почему-то, а как ее овобождать непонятно и слишком сложно), к тому же на заграничных сайтах все в один голос кричат что это ужос-ужос.

Какие есть другие варианты для такой организации данных? Если придется создать 4 класса для 4-х уровней вложенности, сразу говорю что это не подходит.

Comment: Чет это вдруг дофига памяти? Вы там решили базу яндекса хранить? 
>Если придется создать 4 класса для 4-х уровней вложенности, сразу говорю что это не подходит. 
С каких это пор ООП не подходит?

Comment: Не поверите, простейший массив) Просто возвращаю когда его функцией (функция вызывается в цикле), память постоянно увеличивается (использую ARC), а как его выкинуть полностью из памяти непонятно, т.е. похоже что выкидывается автоматически только первый уровень, а дальше нет. Пробовал autoreleasepool, не помогло (вот здесь уже вопрос задавал http://hashcode.ru/questions/315644/objective-c-mutable-массивы-и-память ).

По поводу ООП: а если у меня будет 10 функций, которые будут возвращать массивы 5 уровня вложенности, и каждый разной структуры?

Comment: > а если у меня будет 10 функций, которые будут возвращать массивы 5 уровня вложенности, и каждый разной структуры?  

В этом случае, возможно, следует задуматься об упрощении всей архитектуры приложения.

Comment: Если вы про организацию данных, то там и так все настолько просто, что уже упрощать некуда :) Что такое архитектура приложения не знаю, сорри)

Comment: вообще судя по описанию должно по идее освобождать, если только вы где-то еще сохраняете дополнительные ссылки на это дело. Можете привести код?

Comment: > Просто возвращаю когда его функцией (функция вызывается в цикле), память постоянно увеличивается

такое ощущение, то там или рекурсия, или мы загоняем в память все данные, чтоб найти(сохранить) нужное.

нужен кусок кода

Comment: @baduga ну во-первых в objective-c не гоняются данные, гоняются только ссылки на адресное пространство. Во-вторых, что-то подсказывает, что Вы либо не правильно готовите массив, либо не правильно с ним работаете.

Comment: @tragvar, запостил фрагмент кода здесь: http://hashcode.ru/questions/315644/objective-c-mutable-массивы-и-память

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CoreData в помощь, если нужна такая сложная структура с большой вложенностью, почему бы не создать нормальную модель данных с нормальными объетами и связями? NSOrderedSet relationships и NSManagedObjects все что нужно

Comment: >Если придется создать 4 класса для 4-х уровней вложенности, сразу говорю что это не подходит.

Comment: ну так и не создавайте, можно создать один класс и по признакам фетчить их из базы предикатами когда нужно, то есть ваще не использовать даже связи, а строить все на NSFetchRequest

Comment: опишите подробнее задачу или пример приведите

Comment: согласен про CoreData. когда-то делал "екзамен гаи по билетам", там была вложенность четыре, хватало обычного plist для вытягивания верного ответа из "массив билетов - массив вопросов к билету - массив ответов к вопросу - что-то еще, не помню" ну и массивы в NSDictionary :)

upd. точнее наоборот, данные были в словорях, а словари в массивах

Answer (score 1):

Память  при использовании циклов в неглавном потоке может не освобождаться, потому что цикл блокирует управление, из-за чего очистка autoreleasepool просто не вызывается. Есть большая разница между

```
    for (;;) {
       @autoreleasepool {
          // .. создание autorelease объектов
       }
    }
```

и

```
    @autoreleasepool {
       for (;;) {
              // .. создание autorelease объектов
       }
    }
```

Нужно использовать первый вариант